# Let $A$ be a reducible non-negative matrix. It is true that $A$ has a positive eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in M_n$ be a reducible non-negative matrix.

Is it true that  $A$ has a positive eigenvector?

Comment: What does "positive vector" mean?

Comment: @Crostul The $0$ matrix has a whole bunch of eigenvectors...

Comment: Yes, and at least one has all positive entries.

Comment: Even without reducibility, there's an easy proof that there's a nonneg evec (i.e., all entries $\ge 0$): Consider the positive octant of the unit sphere. $x \mapsto Ax$ is a continuous self-map of this disk, hence has a fixed point by Brouwer. That's a nonnegative eigenvector. But strictly positive? I don't see a quick and easy proof.

Comment: @JohnHughes How do you say that it is a self-map? The matrix may have large norm.

Comment: Sorry: I meant that $x \mapsto \frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}$ is a self-map. I wish this were my own idea, but it's something I picked up in my ugrad days 40 years ago in a topology class. :(

Answer (score 2):

EDIT. The answer to the edited question is obviously NO. Have a look at the instance $diag(1,2)$.

Overall I feel that you have not thought more than one second about this question.

I hope that my friend Nizar is very happy with this edited answer.